# Hosting gRPC server on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-services, grpc, windows-server-2016, .net-framework-version

I am currently working my way into gRPC. So far, I've created a gRPC server which runs on my machine as a service and listens on localhost. This works fine, when starting the client I get the expected results. Both client and server are targeting .Net framework 4.5.1.

However, I want to run the server as a service on a Windows Server 2016 and access it via a client from machines in the same domain.

All tutorials and examples I've found only show how to do it on localhost, which doesn't work when connecting to another machine. Can someone point me in the right direction of a guide or explain to me what to do to make the connection?

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? i have the same :(

Comment: @blindmeis In my case, I had to make exceptions for the used port in the windows firewall, both incoming and going out.

Comment: it seems i miss something else, i cant not get this to work :(. did you open the ports just on the server or also on the client? can you share a running sample project?